# How to forward traffic from one Ethernet interface to another?

Tags: ubuntu, routing, iptables

I have a LAN (192.168.88.0/24) and want to give devices on that LAN WAN access (e.g. digitally connect Ethernet interface `enp179s0f1` to `eno1`).

How can I forward traffic from one Ethernet interface to another so that a device `192.168.88.100` can hop through my host's `192.168.88.254` interface to reach `8.8.8.8` via the WAN connection, Ethernet interface `eno1`?

```
me:~$ netstat -r
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
default         100.22.33.254   0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eno1
100.99.64.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U         0 0          0 eno1
192.168.88.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 enp179s0f1
```

Comment: Routing, i.e. accepting traffic that is destined to a different device and forwarding it to that device or the next routing hop, is disabled on Linux by default. You enable it with `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`. Do that and try. To make that change permanent, i.e. resilient to reboots: `echo net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 > /etc/sysctl.d/99-ip-forward.conf`. In my experience, this is all you need to do.

Comment: No, that's not enough to just enable ip forwarding. In addition to that, either back-facing routes should be established on the next router (a `100.22.33.254` needs a route to 192.168.88.0/24), or NAT instantiated on this machine, `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.88.0/24 -o eno1 -j MASQUERADE`). P.S. use `ip route` command to view routing table. It produces cleaner output.

Comment: And of course, `192.168.88.254` needs to be the default gateway on the other `192.168.88.0/24` hosts (well, or just the host `192.168.88.100`, depending on what you want). Make sure the firewall on `192.168.88.254` does not block forwarding traffics as well.